# I'm confused about when to use で vs を in this sentence

Tags: particles, particle-を, particle-で

I want to ask whether or not it is okay to use a pen. Should I use

> ボールペンでつかってもいいですか。

or

> ボールペンをつかってもいいですか。

Answer (score 2):

で denotes the means by which the verb is performed:

> ペンで書{か}きました。　
> I wrote with a pen.

を marks the object of the verb i.e. the thing the verb acts on.

> ペンを使{つか}ってもいいですか。
> Is it okay to use a pen.

Here's another pair of examples where you can see the difference more clearly:

> 箸{はし}で食{た}べました。
> I ate with chopsticks.
> 箸{はし}を食{た}べました。
> I ate the chopsticks.